# How to send message from one socket.io node application to other socket.io node application

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my node application I need to send message to other node application using socket.io. Because depending upon the first application results I need to do some tasks in second application. How can I do this?

```
         var express=require('express');
         var http=require('http');
         var app=express();
          app.configure(function(){
           app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
          });

        var server = http.createServer(app);


       var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');
       socket.on('connect', function(){
            socket.on('connected', function(data){

             console.log('connected');
           });
            socket.on('disconnect', fucntion(){

            console.log('disconnected');
             });
       });


      var io = require('socket.io-client').listen(server);
      server.listen(6509);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `socket.io-client` in order to use socket.io as a client in your nodejs server side.

Here is an example how to work with this client:

On you'r server

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.on('event', function(data){});
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});
```

For more information on how to achieve this task see: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client

Comment: thanks for ur usefull post..now i will try to use this in my appln.

Comment: i have tried socket.io-client.but it showing following error in 1st line.. TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: here is a working example, try customizing it for your needs:

var serverAddress = '127.0.0.1';
var serverPort = 3000;

var clientio = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = clientio.connect(serverAddress , { port: serverPort });
socket.on('connect', function(){
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
});

Comment: i dont know clearly abt how to use socket.io-client..i want to emit one event in one node application and get that event in other node application.For this i dont know where to use the socket.io-client in first application or in second application.

Comment: I will write a blog post tutorial about it and post the link here, stay tuned :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client').connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function(){
       socket.on('connected', function(data){

             console.log('connected');
       });
       socket.on('disconnect', function(){

            console.log('disconnected');
       });
});
```